# Почему при удалении удаляется первый элемент массива? А если написать через оператор switch case не работает break в последнем условии?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему при вводе команды delete удаляется только первый элемент массива, а не тот который мне нужен? например я ввожу add Tom, add John, add Tim, в массив добавляются ["Tom", "John", "Tim"], но если ввиду delete John, удаляется Tom.

```
let arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < Infinity; i++) {
    var command = prompt('Введите команду');
    var arrays = command.split(' ');

    var index = arrays[0];
    var name = arrays[1];

     if (index == 'add') {
         arr.push(name);
         console.log(arr);
     } else if (index == 'delete') {
        arr.splice(name, 1);
         console.log(arr);
     } else if (index === 'stop') {
         break;
     }
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: вы прочитайте сначала документацию к splice прежде чем первым параметром имя пихать

Comment: оператор switch также испоьзует break, так что брейк влияет именно на него, а не на цикл

Comment: а как мне тогда остановить цикл? почему если через else if пишу условие и break цикл останавливается а через switch case нет. ведь  else if (index === 'stop') {
         break;
     }  это тоже самое что switch (index) { case 'stop':  break; }

Comment: я вроде написал, что это совсем не то же самое. есть for-break а есть switch-case-break. Ознакомьтесь с синтаксисом оператора switch. Можете условие удаления обработать через иф, остальное запихать в свитч.

Comment: _ведь else if (index === 'stop') { break; } это тоже самое что switch (index) { case 'stop': break; }_ - очевидно, что это НЕ то же самое ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: _«а как мне тогда остановить цикл?»_ - для этого можно использовать метки (тотально забытый функционал JS): `loop:{\n}for (....) { switch (....) { .... case something: break loop; }}` - но хз что при этом будет со свитчем, тестируй)) Вообще можно просто в функцию обернуть и return'ить что надо когда надо.

Comment: @Grundy, ты не в курсе, почему [при брейке по метке](https://jsbin.com/bayevakive/edit?js,console) свитч тоже брейкается? Это конечно удобно, но слегка неожиданно по-моему... имхо, логичнее предполагать что вложенный оператор завершит свое выполнение. **upd:** Судя по MDN, такое поведение все-таки ожидаемое (стандартное?).

Comment: @yar85, наоборот, логично, что при прерывании "родительского" цикла останавливается и текущий, вызывающий `break`. Это можно сравнить с `return` для вмещающей функции: https://jsfiddle.net/1m4gu3Lc/

Comment: @Leonid, нене, смотри: семантика "прервать <операторПоМетке>", то есть относится к метке (к одному конкретному оператору с ней) - поэтому прерывание также и вложенных операторов мне кажется не совсем логичным (почему бы вложенным не завершить свое выполнение? то что js-энжн заодно прерывает **все** вложенные операторы поддерживающие `break`, это уже его самодеятельность, пусть и стандартная: ему "не сказано" так делать, он сам решает).

Comment: Я понял, но по сути использовать label можно только в отношении текущего либо вышестоящего цикла, к дочернему его применять смысла нет. А прерывание выполнения вмещающего блока кода прекращает и любое действие внутри, это логично. Я когда-то по дурости много использовал эти label и именно такого поведения и ожидал)) Иначе бы еще более внутренние циклы продолжили свое действие, а суть и была в том, чтобы прервать любые вычисления. Потом я узнал о рекурсии))

Comment: @Leonid, реакции "в моих задачах это логичнее" / "так лучше и удобнее" понятны - но речь выше была о другом, а именно об ожидаемости поведения в общем и целом: оператор `break` императивный, поэтому следует ожидать именно императивного (строго определенного семантикой) выполнения действий, без какой-либо "магии". Но магия по факту есть, и это противоречие **нелогично**. Оно может сбивать с толку некоторых программистов. Сравнение с `return` неуместно, т.к. последний предусматривает вызов (изменение стека вызовов), в отличие от управляющих операторов и оп. ветвления с "плоским" выполнением.

Comment: @Leonid, другими словами, семантика `return` совершенно иная: немедленный возврат из функции. И его поведение соответствует. Но представь на минутку, что этот оператор вызывает выталкивание из стека вызовов не одной записи (возврат из одной функции), а сразу нескольких (возврат и из текущей функции, и из родительской, и из родительской родительской, и т.д.) - это уже было бы произволом интерпретатора. Такой произвол не ожидается. Вот и с `break` та же ситуация: программист кодом четко говорит что выполнить, но интерпретатор выполняет помимо этого лишние действия, о которых ему не было сказано.

Comment: @Leonid, более императивным поведением было бы прерывание цикла с немедленным прекращением его текущей итерации, **но с завершением выполнения текущего оператора**. То есть - выход из цикла **после** свитча, если брать наш пример. И как следствие, возможность прервать свитч дополнительным брейком, уже локальным. Ты несогласен с этим?

Comment: Вся разница лишь в том, что нет возможности инструкцией `return` завершить родительскую функцию. А инструментарий циклов более развит, так как это основа основ. И по этой же причине `label`, да и `continue` перестали быть популярными с развитием других семантических конструкций.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129395/discussion-between-yar85-and-leonid).

Answer (score 0):

Как указано в справке [`.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) первым параметром указывается *индекс* элемента.

В коде в вопросе идет попытка передать *сам элемент*. Идет попытка привести значение к целому числу. Так как в элементе вообще не число, результатом приведения будет `0`.

Все это приводит к вызову `.splice(0,1)` - что и является удалением одного элемента, начиная с индекса `0`.

Для решения нужно сначала найти индекс элемента и затем использовать его.

Для поиска индекс есть метод [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
var index = arr.indexOf(name);

if (index > -1) // если что-то нашли
    arr.splice(index, 1); // удалили по найденному индексу
```

Comment: Прошу уточнить: *Так как в элементе вообще не число, результатом приведения будет 0* === С логическим значением понятно - *false/true* преобразовываются в число 0/1, Возможно, пустая строка и *null*  по тому же принципу (*Number('')*, *Number(null)*) Но почему *'текст'* и *NaN* приводятся к нулю? Т.е. какой принцип или логика преобразования всего этого разнообразия? Кстати, во втором параметре "нечисло" тоже воспринимается как 0 (*splice(2, 'текст')*) , т.е. *splice* ничего не удаляет.

Comment: @vikttur_Stop_RU_war_in_UA, при приведении параметра к числу вызывается внутренняя функция [ToInteger](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-tointeger), которая в случае `NaN` возвращает `0`

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо.